# Clang - "symbol not found" when linking

Tags: c++, c, clang

I'm trying to compile this source in clang:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) TEST(int num)
{
return;
}
```

Problem is that on link, clang reports "Cannot export _TEST: symbol not found"

I can't find a way, however, to prevent clang from mangling names

I've been reading that this is a bug in clang, but it's hard to believe they haven't fixed it by now

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS are you using to compile? I ask because I have noticed that on Mac OS X and its Mach-O ABI, all symbols are prepended with `_`, while the same compilers omit the `_` on Linux and its ELF format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of the `.drectve` section of the generated assembly file by clang contains:

```
.section    .drectve,"r"
.ascii  " -export:_TEST"
```

while it should've been as it with gcc:

```
.section    .drectve,"r"
.ascii  " -export:TEST"
```

You can work around it by removing `__declspec(dllexport)` and creating a file `file.s` containing the symbols you want to export as the following:

```
.section .drectve,"r"
    # list of symbols you want to export
    .ascii " -export:TEST"
```

keep an empty line at the end, it's not displayed here.

When ever you want to export a symbol add `.ascii " -export:SYMBOL_NAME"`. Now you can compile it with:

```
clang++ file.cpp file.s -shared -o file.dll
```

it should work fine.